# Are these expressions are right use of object complements?

Tags: object-complements

> **A**: I hope you serve that food **hot**.
>
> **B**: I hope you write those letters **tall and straight**.

Each of the above sentences seems to have an **object complement** marked in bold.
Are they correct?

Can I also say like below?( <= Is this a grammatically correct question?)

> **C**: I hope you draw the line **thick**.
>
> **D**: I hope you find the gift **excellent**.

Thank you for your help very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are correct.  As it says [here](http://www.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/objects.htm):

> An object complement follows and modifies or refers to a direct object. It can be a noun or adjective or any word [or words] acting as a noun or adjective.

Your examples C and D are also correct.  Your question is grammatically correct, but it sounds awkward; it would seem that your instincts are good!  I would simply write "Are the sentences below also correct?"

Comment: Thank you very very much for your elaborate answer and help! What an elegant English teacher that teaches **joy of learning English!**